# Debian installer fails to start

Tags: debian, boot, usb

Recently on my 2013 HP Envy laptop, the performance has been dropping so i decided to install debian since I use it on my other systems. It uses Intel i7, so I downloaded the amd64 live image with Xfce desktop. I mounted this on a USB drive because there is no CD/DVD drive. I disabled secure boot, and enabled legacy support in the BIOS, but when I select to boot from the USB drive, nothing happens. I just get a screen with a blinking cursor. No "`isolinux.bin missing or corrupt", no "No bootable device found.`" Nothing. I have completely reformatted the drive with dd and rereimaged it twice, with the same result. Another thing to note is that the drive is not detected at all by the resident Windows installation. I am frustrated with my device, please help.

Comment: How did you "mount" the iso image on the usb drive?

Comment: I used dd to write it to the one partition of the USB.

Comment: Ah, use dd to write it to the whole device, e.g. /dev/sdx, not to a partition like /dev/sdx1

Comment: run `dd` theǹ `sync` : `dd if=.. of=.. && sync`

Comment: Or use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, converting a comment into an answer. We discovered via the comments that the poster was using `dd` to write to the first partition on the device, i.e. `/dev/sdx1` rather than the device as a whole, `/dev/sdx`. The result of this is that there was nothing usable where the master boot record should live (assuming it was booting as a hard drive) and the CDROM signature was also missing (in the unlikely case that it was trying to boot as an optical device).

Using the whole device

```
   dd if=image.iso bs=1M of=/dev/sdx conv=fsync
```

fixed the issue